# How to apply Ziegler–Nichols to a heater-termometer system?

Tags: pid-controller

This is not a production project (though I don't mind it having practical value), but an undergraduate thesis. I already have an onoff controller  with hysteresis and that works fine. I am hoping to compare results and show that a pid is "better".

The process I need to control is the temperature on the surface of a 50W heater. For this I am using an Atmel implementation of a parallel structure classical pid. The input and output type is `int16_t` i.e. signed.

Consequently, the power to the heater is controlled in this way (pseudocode):

```
if(pid_return < 0) set_heater(0%);
else               set_heater(100% * pid_return / INT16_MAX)
```

To apply Ziegler–Nichols, I need to try different P controllers and identify the one, which causes consistent oscillations, then measure amplitude and period. In the light of the limitation from the previous paragraph, how should this procedure be adjusted?

Comment: Temperature control is highly non-linear process. And it also suffering from slow response times.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see the process as, on one side, rise in temperature, proportional to applied electrical power, and on the other an exponential cooling, for example Stefan-Bolzman. Is this correct? Is this a problem?

Comment: There is a couple of problems. As I've mentioned already - a slow response to your heating command. The second is that you don't have any control over the cooling. You *can* get it working somehow, but the methods for tuning good for classical LTIs are not good here.

Comment: @EugeneSh. quite alarming. Can you recommend another __simple__ method for tuning this system? On another note: the thermometer being on the surface of the heater, the temperature gradient is about 5-10 degrees per minute.

Comment: @EugeneSh. -- $100 autotuning ramp/soak PID temperature controllers are a dime a dozen -- http://www.omega.com/pptst/CN38S.html for example, and omega runs on the expensive side.  This is not a hard problem.

Comment: Try a bit of hysteresis and turn it into a bang-bang type controller. How much inaccuracy can you tolerate in your surface temperature?

Comment: @Andyaka The thing is, this is not a production project (though I don't mind it having practical value). This is a bechelor's thesis. I already have an onoff with hysteresis and that works fine. I was hoping to compare results and show that a pid is "better".

Comment: @Vorac, Slightly off-topic, but beware of confirmation bias.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Metaphor breakdown alert: $100 controllers are $1200 a dozen (excluding bulk discount). ;^)